# Cutting big corners consisting of squares into smaller ones

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

> Let's call a chocolate piece which has a form of a corner and consists of 3 squares 1 х 1
>
> [image: see picture, not-to-scale]
>
> **a small corner.**  Let's call a chocolate piece which has a form of a corner and consists of 3 squares n х n
>
> [image: see example for n=2, not-to-scale]
>
> **a big corner.**
>
> At which $n$ can a large corner be cut along the grid lines of a
> chocolate bar into small corners?

A small corner is the main element of a large corner. Therefore the sum of cells in the corners must divide by 3, and this condition is fulfilled automatically, since this sum is equal to $3*n*n$. The problem seems to be solved, yet there should be a system which is more complicated than the thoughts that I have now.

I am now checking one-by-one.

Comment: For $n=5$, start with $n=3$ in the center.